# copying file from UNC path to startup folder on Windows 7 machines

Tags: windows-7, boot, cmd.exe

I have sucessfully figured out how to copy a file to "\machinename\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\startup" however I want to run this as part of an existing startup batchfile. I would like it to be able to find out if the file already exists and if so, ignore it. I'll admit I am a total noob at this and I know there is some sort of paramater or switch that would do this. can anyone assist?

script is:

> `copy "\\server\share\file.txt" "\\MachineName\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"`

I would like it to say

```
IF "File.txt" exists in "C\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
Then ignore. 
copy "\\server\share\file.txt" "\\MachineName\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go replace copy file cmmand with your copy command

- Edit replace PATH\FILE with the destination you are checking.

  if NOT EXISTS PATH\FILE ( copy file command here )

Comment: Thanks for assistance, I tried this but it fell over with this error: C\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start was unexpected at this time. looks like it does not like the space between Start menu, any ideas? 

So this is my command: 
if NOT EXISTS C\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start menu\programs\startup\file.txt (copy "\\server\path\file.txt" "C\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\programs\startup\)

Comment: try putting quotes around the path in the if statement? for example "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start menu\programs\startup\file.txt"

Comment: @Laurence The actual syntax is `if [not] exist <some command here>`. Notice there's no ending "S".

Comment: whoops my bad.. yeah no S :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if exist "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\file.txt" (
    copy "\\server\share\file.txt" "\\MachineName\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\file.txt"
)
```